# Adding Characters to the Begining of an Array that form words

Tags: javascript, arrays

When looking at set of characters I am trying to put each letter into a specifc order in an array. For Example: Given the Strings "cat" and "dog" I would want an array that contains `[d,o,g,c,a,t]`, cat at the end of the array because it was read first.

Currently I have tried this:

However, when I try the code below assuming the strings are "cat" and "dog". 
 I get an array containing: `[c,a,t,d,o,g]`. Instead of push I have also tried `.unshift` but the array now reads: `[g,o,d,t,a,c]`.

```
  var chars = /^[a-z]$/;
  var string = [];
  function makeword(){
    if(currentChar.match(chars)){
    string.push(currentChar);
    currentChar = getNextChar(); //Gets next Character in the String
    makeword();
    }
  }
```

Is something like this possible in Javascript?

Comment: where you have defined currentChar ??

Comment: what is your example input? How will you give it? is is a string which you will pass which is broken into an array? Or will you just pass a plain array? Please give a proper detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to provide a list of strings, then have them show up in an array in reverse order, with each letter as an element of the array. The following function will do just that:

```
function makeWords() {
  var arr = [];

  for(var i = arguments.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
    arr.push(arguments[i]);
  }

  return arr.join('').split('');
}
```

so running `makeWords('cat', 'dog')` will result in `['d','o','g','c','a','t']`.

Comment: Just use [`Array.reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) on the `arguments` array...

Comment: @Quill, just an FYI, its good practive to [avoid leaking the arguments](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#32-leaking-arguments) "array".

Answer (score 0):

It's a relatively simple code when a functional approach is used. The rest and spread operators are very handy both to collect the function arguments and to spread the characters of a word into an array.

```js
var characterify = (...c) => c.reduceRight((a,b) => a.concat([...b]) ,[]);

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(characterify("cat","dog")) + "</pre>");
```